# using @Html.React in my .net MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, reactjs

I did the comments tutorial on http://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html and got it to render server side using .net mvc.

I have an existing mvc app where I rewrote a page in react. I'm trying to render it server side but get this message:

"'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper>' does not contain a definition for 'React' and no extension method 'React' " - the error refers to the "@Html.React" code in my view.

```
@Html.React("TopicAnswers", new
{
    initialAnswers = Model,
    url = Url.Action("TopicAnswers", new { id = ViewBag.TopicID }),
})
```

I have the same files downloaded from Nuget as the tutorial. I tried this at the top of my view to no avail:

```
@using React;
```

In my ReactConfig.cs file, I see a "using React;" at the top and in the code, this is fine:

```
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
                .AddScript("~/Scripts/internal/eusVote/TopicAnswers.jsx");
```

One more thing. My view is in /Areas/Subfolder/Views

Why does my code complain about @Html.React in my view?

Comment: try to add namespace in web.config which is located in `Views` folder

Comment: @SnakeEyes Awesome. I added React.Web.MVC namespace to the respective web.config in the Views folder and that did it. Actually got another error but at least this part is resolved. You guys are amazing. Muchos gracias. - BTW, the reason it wasn't working was because the view was in an Areas subfolder and not the main View folder. Thus, I had to add namespace to the "internal" web.config. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to put following using statement in your View

```
using System.Web.Optimization.React;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this using statement for React MVC in your view:

```
@using React.Web.Mvc
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC Core 2.1 this helper extension is now within React.AspNet:

```
@using React.AspNet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<add namespace="React.Web.Mvc" />
```

to your Web.config in your View folder.